# How can we install AriaMaestosa on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: software-installation, midi

How can we install a current version of AriaMaestosa on Ubuntu 19.10? IMHO it's the very best MIDI editor around, and their PPA hasn't been updated for a long time.

Comment: From the upstream project itself: [How to compile AriaMaestosa from source](https://ariamaestosa.github.io/ariamaestosa/docs/building.html)

Comment: Since this project seems to lack volunteers to do the packaging, consider gathering a couple like-minded friends and adopting the packaging for this project. Developers generally don't do the packaging - community volunteers do.